# How To Concatenate Rows and Show in Columns in Excel

Tags: datetime, excel-2010, concatenation

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUwb3.jpg)

Hello Everyone,

I Have Column **A** as Date and **B,C,D,E,F** as Time. I want to concatenate it

**J1 = A1 + B1**

**J2 = A1 + C1**

**J3 = A1 + D1**

**J4 = A1 + E1**

**J5 = A1 + F1**

then

**J6 = A2 + B2**

**J7 = A2 + C2**

**J8 = A2 + D2**

**J9 = A2 + E2**

**J10 = A2 + F2**

as so on......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **J1** through **J5** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))+INDEX(B:B,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))+INDEX(C:C,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))+INDEX(D:D,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))+INDEX(E:E,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))+INDEX(F:F,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
```

Then copy this block of formulas down as far as needed.

***NOTE:***

If the data is Text rather than real date/time, use **&** rather than **+**.

**EDIT#1:**

This little macro assumes that row #1 is the header row and that the actual data starts of row #2:

```
Sub Jani()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 2
    For i = 2 To N
        For j = 2 To 6
            Cells(K, "J").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value + Cells(i, j).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @JaniMani  **Yes** we can do a script..........Do you want the script to fill column **J** with *formulas* or with *values* ??

Comment: Yeah i would prefer script

Comment: @JaniMani Do you want the script to fill column **J** with **formulas** or with **values** ??

Comment: I need Values Only

Comment: @JaniMani  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: you are ROCK MAN (Y). Thanks for your help

Comment: @JaniMani  Thanks for the feedback!